# Swagger UI not loading in Azure Function due to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'openApiContext'

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-functions, swagger

I am getting the below error as soon as I try to load the Swagger. This is an Azure Function with .NET 3 runtime stack running in VS 2022.

If I try to send a request to the localhost from Postman, it works. Only the Swagger UI is not loading.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the method definition for the function `RenderSwaggerUI`?

Comment: That is not a user defined method. Its definition is not visible to me. Is there are a way I can view it?

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that these were Functions from an external lib. In that case, I think it's most likely a configuration and/or dependency issue that I can't help with. Maybe if you show us how you configure swagger/include it in your project. :)

Comment: I am using the default Azure Functions Http Trigger with OpenAPI option. I did not configure the Swagger manually.

Answer (score -1):

I have created the .NET 3.1 Azure Function Http Trigger with Open API and tested the **Swagger UI API** in browser and Postman as well:

**.csproj file**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

In Postman:

[image]

In the browser, Swagger UI is working good:

[image]

Comment: Yes, when I also create a new Azure Function, it works. But I am getting error in the existing Azure Function. If I create a new one and then migrate my current code there, it start behaving the same way.

Comment: Then there is issue with the existing code (have you made any changes to that code. If yes, please post with the clear data in the new question)